# Client-side web service caching policy for a slow and unreliable service

Tags: php, web-services, api, caching

I'm trying to figure out the best way to cache a slow and unreliable service.  Right now, every time the service goes down, all page requests start to take a long time because the cache never gets filled and the service is queried every time. The service is not providing data that is essential to the page. How should I cache this to make it work well for me?

I don't think it really matters, but I'm using PHP 5 and and the service is SOAP.

Comment: you may want to explore HTML5 Local Storage API. refer http://24ways.org/2010/html5-local-storage for more on this top. what does the service provide to the page ? is it textual data, field values, numbers etc ? more info would help

Comment: Possible solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21389823/is-there-a-free-online-data-cache-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Five years later, Netflix has solved this problem with their very useful "Hystrix" library.

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix

Answer (score 0):

I'd serialize() the received data structure and write it to a file.

If the PHP app requests new data, I'd unserialize() the data from the file and return it directly. After a certain amount of time, the next request reloads the resource from remote and serialize() again to the file.

**Update:**

How about injecting *up-front* in every relevant page some default Json data, which the client uses as a *reply* if the service doesn't reply fast enough?

Comment: You've described caching. But how does it answer my question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm implementing a webservice cache for php at the moment.

It's no rocket science. All is need is a persistence (I choose sqlite because access to the sqlite file ist faster then to a "normal" file. RAMdisk would probably even faster) and a simple class or function that controls reading and writing access to the persistence.

Using a file instead of calling the service saves about 95% of time :)