# Is there a free online data cache service?

Tags: ajax, caching, cloud, storage

I am building a mashup, which gets data from rather slow external API and processes it at client side. To speed things up, I would like to add a simple cache which will store processed results online, but I don't want to buy a dedicated server. Is there a free online service to cache any JSON/XML/text data using AJAX?

Comment: What's wrong with this question? It is technical, related to programming.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found some solutions:

- [YQL Caching](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20%2a%20from%20yahoo.caching%20where%20cache_key%20=%20%27some%20key%27%20and%20%20cache_value%20=%20%27some%20value%27%20and%20timeout%20=%20%27604800%27%20and%20put%20=%20%271%27) - free 2000 requests/hour/IP
- [OpenKeyVal](http://openkeyval.org) - free 64KB buckets
- [IronCache](http://www.iron.io) - free 100MB & 10M requests/month
- [GarantiaData](http://garantiadata.com) - free 25MB in-memory cache
- [Parse](https://parse.com) - free 1M requests/month
- [Amazon ElastiCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) - free 750h of Micro Cache Node
- [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com) - free 100MB storage
- [MemCachier](https://www.memcachier.com) - free 25 MB in-memory cache

If you know more, please expand this list.